# Javascript : callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am using vanilla javascript to making AJAX call to my APIs.

Below is my code which i am calling on click of a simple button:

```
    getUserByUserId : function (callback){

        var userid = localStorage.getItem('userid');
        var userApiUrl = "http://174.129.30.174:8080/users/"+userid;

        var xmlhttp = micropaywall.getAjaxInstance();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", userApiUrl, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

But i get "callback is not a function" at line

**callback(xmlhttp.responseText);**

Below is my callback function :

```
getUserByUserIdCallback : function(response){

          if(response != "")
          { 
              var res = JSON.parse(response);
              var arrAppid = res.appIds;
              var userid = res._id;
              localStorage.setItem('appid', arrAppid[0]);
              var appid = localStorage.getItem('appid');
              micropaywall.getUserAccountDetails(userid, appid);
          }
      }
```

Please correct me where I am making mistake.

Comment: How are you binding the click event to the button? Ensure that you are indeed passing `getUserByUserIdCallback` as the first argument to it.

Comment: @techfoobar I am binding it this way
<input type="submit" value="User Dashboard" onclick="getUserByUserId();" class="btn-pay" />

Comment: That should be `<input type="submit" value="User Dashboard" onclick="getUserByUserId(X);" class="btn-pay" />` - Where `X` is `yourObject.getUserByUserIdCallback` (`yourObject here is the parent object containing the function getUserByUserIdCallback)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line in question and examine the value of `callback`. You're likely to find that its null or undefined. Then think about why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change the "callback" function then you can just call it directly:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    getUserByUserIdCallback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

You would only need to pass in a callback function if you want different behavior when calling the `getUserByUserId` function.